# J2ME common api for all phone models

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I am new to J2ME application development. Normally I have developed j2me apps for Nokia phone s60 series and in PC using emulator(with Netbeans IDE). I think that emulator has Nokia infrastructures to run mobile apps.
When I tried to run the same simple j2me application which ran on a Nokia phone, on a Sony Ericson, Motorola, it did not work. I have heard that j2me apis are little bit different phone Vendor to Vendor. Will I  have to use Sony Ericson and Motorola J2ME API and develop separate app for each brand? Cannot I use a common J2ME api for all mobile phones? Or any solutions to use a common api for all mobile phones. (The application features can be limited to the phone's performance, version, series and its support. It is ok. Here my question is about a common api. My question may be similar to [can we develop a j2me application that work in all mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116224/can-we-develop-a-j2me-application-that-work-in-all-mobile-devices). But I couldn't find good answer.)

Comment: Have you tried to run your apps on Samsung phones? In particular the Samsung SGH A157?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [J2MEPolish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/). This is very large library that should provide level of abstraction between the application developer and the concrete platform. But it takes some time to learn it. Probably easier way is just to refer to the concrete phone documentation and use only JSRs that are supported by concrete model. There is a trick that allows you to check that concrete JSR is supported. You can call `Class.forName()` for some class from specific JSR. If exception is thrown JSR is not supported. The advantage of J2MEPolish is that it helps you to generate version per device type.

Comment: Thank you Alex.If I use J2MEPolish (I referred your link)which is a cross-platform development,can we avoid all issues of mobile phone vendor changes,vendor's package changes & CLDC and MIDP version?Using Polish is a good solution?As you mentioned,developing apps referring the documents and JSR for a particular model is good and no issues may arise.But if we have to develop our app to be installed & used in more models,we ll have to develop apps altering apps model to model.(Wouldn't it be hard task?)I have used LWUIT but not J2MEPolish.LWUIT is not a good cross-Platform development.isn't it?

Comment: @ Aash, No. LWUIT supports Symbian, Blackberry and Android. Its good one. Why do you feel its not good? Are you getting any difficulties?

Comment: Thank Bharath. No difficulty with LWUIT.I love it.My J2ME apps didn't work on Sony Erricson and but supported Nokia. My Main target is smart phones. Please any one tell me that if we use our libraries and j2ME,don't we bother with Vendor's  api and their installed kvm? I want to develop one application to be suitable and supported to more models of many vendors.I am not supposed to develop more apps for model to model.I d consider only about J2ME CLDC and MIDP versions and develop few apps for different MIDP versions.

Comment: @ Aash, Sony Ericsson supports Java ME. Have you use [Sony Ericsson Java ME platform?](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/other/java/sdk?cc=gb&lc=en) Java ME application can't run directly on Android enabled Sony Ericsson devices.

Comment: Thanks Bharath.Actually I tried to run a simple app developed with LWUIT on a Sony Ericsson and that phone is not enabled Android.But it didn't work.but on Noika.Why do I use Sony Ericsson Java ME Platform to develop applications for sony ericsson ,cannot I use only the J2ME ?not only for ecricsson, Motoroal,and other brands? (I know there are vendor specific packages available and there are some alternatives vendor to vendor )(Will I have to use vendors'Java ME Platform??)This is my main problem too.A Common J2ME plateform to develop apps for all brands.... ??

Comment: @Aash, What Sony Ericsson mobile you have tested?

Comment: k750. If I set the MIDP 2.0, a phone which supports MIDP 2.1 can run that MIDP 2.0 app?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you used packages which are strictly part of the J2ME Framework you should not have any issues. You need however, to keep an eye out for the MIDP and CLDC version that the phone supports.

Different MIDP and CLDC versions provide you with different apis, running a piece of code designed for MIDP 2.0 on something which does not support it will eventually cause errors. Maybe [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/about-java-me-395899.html) Oracle Page will help you solve any queries you might have.